# Missing boot files in Windows 8

Tags: boot, windows-8-preview, bootloader

I had a partition with Windows 8 Release Preview, Windows' System Reserved partition and the empty space of the beginning of disk. I moved two partitions to the beginning of disk using Ubuntu Live CD and GParted.

After that, the Windows Loader didn't boot and throw an error about missing files. I fixed it using the commands:

```
bootsect /nt60 sys /force /mbr
bootrec /rebuildbcd
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
```

When I used "Automatic repair" option from "Advanced boot" menu, it throw an error like:

> Windows can't fix your boot problems. For more information see file C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt

In this file I found a description of the system repair actions and at the end of file:

> Boot status indicates that the OS booted successfully.

Now, when I use the Advanced boot menu from Windows 8 (PC settings -> General -> Advanced startup) I receive an error:

> Restart your PC to try again. It looks like something didn't load correctly. Restarting might fix the problem. If this happens more than once, you might also be able to find help by searching online for the specific error code. Erorr code: 0x8007090.

0x80070490 is the error code ERROR_NOT_FOUND.

What are the missing boot files and how can I restore them?

List of files in System Reserved Partition:

```
B:\bootmgr
B:\BOOTNXT
B:\Boot\BCD
B:\Boot\BCD.LOG
B:\Boot\BCD.LOG1
B:\Boot\BCD.LOG2
B:\Boot\BOOTSTAT.DAT
B:\Boot\Fonts
B:\Boot\memtest.exe
B:\Boot\qps-ploc
B:\Boot\Resources
B:\Boot\Resources\bootres.dll
```

and many *.mui and *.ttf files.

Answer (score 4):

```
bcdboot c:\Windows /s c: /l en-us
```

(this one works like a charm!)

Comment: i restarted windows 9 times, all succesful boot ;)

Comment: Do we need to have the Windows DVD in at the time of running this?

Answer (score 1):

1. You must check that SystemReserved is set as active partition.
2. **`bootsect /nt60 all /force /mbr`**
3. **`bcdboot c:\windows`**  - (assuming `c:\windows` is where Windows 8 is installed. If not change `c:` to correct `drive_letter`.)

Comment: 1. My System Reserved partition is active. 2. I already did it. 3. And it too.

Answer (score 1):

Srttrail.exe  double boot failure followed by automatic repairs.

I did a restore if you can get that far.

Then do a custom install instead of express.
Turn off updates on install.
Allow the computer to boot and create a restore point.
Then try updates.

This worked for me and i tried everything else I could think of.