# Unable to boot (Windows 8.1)

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

I have a problem similar to this: [Missing boot files in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/451277/missing-boot-files-in-windows-8)

I was unable to boot and I found an old rescue CD I had, Wondershare LiveBoot 2012. It booted, but I made a mistake because I clicked on fix MBR, and it was the wrong one (for Windows 7) because LiveBoot is not fully compatible with Windows 8, and I don't even know if my laptop was using MBR or GPT?
Anyway, now it is even worse and I can't even start the repair disks, although I managed to get into LiveBoot again.
I cannot get into safe mode or repair from the laptop either.

When I try the Windows repair/installation disks, I now get a black screen or the message that there is not enough memory to create a RAMdisk.

I tried some solutions in CMD (LiveBoot) but the last step to rebuild the boot sector failed?

I don't know what to do anymore, and it is sad because I think my laptop can still be saved as disk manager says it is healthy.

Comment: Can you recover with the manufacturer's USB recovery key?  Also try making a Windows 10 USB Boot Key try starting with that.

Comment: It's time to extract whatever files you can get to and then simply reinstall Windows.  You should have came to us before you used an incompatible tool.

Comment: @Ramhound could have phrased it a bit more polite, but in general he is right. On this network you will always find people willing to help you, but it is always easier to fix something before it gets even worse.

Comment: I cannot access the recovery any more, not on the hard drive, and not on the CD or USB. I could just a couple of days ago when the problem started, but I hoped to be able to solve the problem. I know I should have at least refreshed the laptop, but I hoped to find a solution. :( My bad. I will try again. The laptop seems to behave in a quite unpredictable way, so if at least I can access the recovery disks again it would be great. (Unfortunately I didn't know LiveBoot was incompatible, I found out later...)

Comment: @DarkDiamond - I am not exactly sure, how what I said, wasn’t polite. The author has given us very little to go off.

Comment: What happens if MBR is deleted? On a rescue disk I have  (I think Mini Windows XP on the Hiren's Boot CD) there is the option to delete it.

Comment: The manufacturer's USB Recovery key should start because it is just installing a new system. Same if you put a new drive in the computer. Windows 10 Install USB should be the same.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will try to find a computer I can download to and give it a go.

Comment: Suddenly I can access the recovery disk again (I got a black screen yesterday). Can you please confirm it is OK to refresh the laptop?

Comment: Yes.  That should work.  In this situation, if it works, you will get a completely fresh install.

Comment: But it should save my files, right?

Comment: I am not sure of your computer recovery. I would not depend on it saving files but it might.

Comment: Refreshing should keep documents and files, but you are right, you never know, so I think I will first access LiveBoot again to save files just in case, and try again later. Hopefully it will work again. I was happy it started again, but it might be better to be cautious and save some files, even if refreshing should save them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Flash a boot USB-drive using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) and whatever OS image works
   for your PC (see bottom or use Linux if you're comfortable).
2. Turn on your PC, spam whatever key it shows to go into
   the BIOS and boot from your USB.
3. Format your hard drive (use FAT32
   if NTFS isn't available so it works with Windows).
4. After formatting, you can go ahead and try to reinstall windows on your main hard
   drive with whatever other Windows bootable media you have.

You can also [create a bootable Windows drive with your USB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d) as well.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to be able to refresh the laptop, but I haven't tried yet because I have to do it on a day when I can be here (near the laptop). Probably the weekend.

Comment: Before formatting, try to use a hard drive recovery tool like [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to see if it can do anything for you in the way of repairing or retrieval.

Comment: Is it easy to use or does it require some special knowledge?

Comment: It's fairly easy if you already know what formatting is. They have a [step-by-step guide](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) as well. Of course, this step might not even work depending on how messed up the filesystem is, and is unnecessary if you don't have critical data on the drive that isn't backed up already.

Comment: The problem is it didn't boot and I tried to fix it with LiveBoot, which added an MBR code for Windows 7, making things worse. Just the code, it didn't touch the partition. I tried that, but for the partition it asked me if it was for Vista or Windows 7, so of course I didn't do anything, but unfortunately it didn't ask me for the code and I didn't know it was for Windows 7. I find out later with a MBR analyzer that said it is for Windows 7. :(

Comment: Would the solution mentioned in this article work for Windows *? Well, the second one, as I had already tried the first one... https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/

Comment: Unclear which solution you're referring to-- My original answer 100% works to get Windows to boot. The TestDisk tool I was referring to in my earlier comment works in Windows 10/8.1/8/7/Vista/XP. The article you linked actually gives you a good answer: `Important: Restoring your Master boot record with the wrong partition table will make your data unreadable and will make it very hard to recover your data later.` So it seems like you should just refer to my answer and use Rufus since the MBR was overwritten.

Comment: OK, thank you. I will buy a new memory stick next week and download the program.

Comment: You can use the checkmark under my answer to mark it as correct. Rufus **will** work to reimage your hard disk. If you run into more issues in a week you can post another question and reference this with whatever additional issues you ran into. FS stuff can be tricky, if you're not sure don't be afraid to post a question!